# Want to execute a JS command without any event

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we execute below JS without any event as it should be shown at the start means on load, without using on load event - Is there any way

```js
function discount() {
  var saadTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0].innerHTML;
  var saad = document.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice")[0].innerHTML;
  var reed = ((saadTotal - saad) / saadTotal) * 100
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reed + "% off";
}
```

```html
<div class="Total">5000</div>
<div class="DiscPrice">3000</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="discount()">Click</button>
```

Comment: What is the meaning and purpose of saying "I want it to load "on load, without using the onload event" ???  It's like saying you need to cut something but don't want to use a knife, or you have a nail and a hammer but don't want to use the hammer.

Comment: That's what your snippet currently does - it runs the code without using the load event.

Comment: Without using an event like on click of button or on load or on scroll etc.

Comment: Maybe not use "bro" next time. It's really disrespectful if you've come here for help.

Comment: So...just call the function, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function discount(){
var saadTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0].innerHTML;
var saad = document.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice")[0].innerHTML;
var reed =((saadTotal - saad)/saadTotal) *100
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reed +"% off";
}

discount();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I want

Comment: It is showing an error brother as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when running with other HTML content

Comment: Can you show the full code? Perhaps something with importing the JS to early. I created a codePen: https://codepen.io/ShawnHelshJS/pen/VwboGdp

Comment: It is running right on Code pen brother . I have pasted some images if you may help

Comment: I pasted complete code on Code Pen and it is running alright but when I am running on VS code it is not showing the `id="demo"` part

Comment: Can I see the HTML file and the place of the <script tag?

Comment: I have putted JS in head element of HTML

Comment: Can you place it just before the closing body tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236239/discussion-between-saad-and-helsh-js).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function discount(){
var saadTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0].innerHTML;
var saad = document.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice")[0].innerHTML;
var reed =((saadTotal - saad)/saadTotal) *100
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reed +"% off";
}
discount(); // Add this line to call the function as soon as JS is loaded
```

```html
<p class="Total">15</p>
<p class="DiscPrice">10</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Then just load your script in the html. No need to trigger any event

Comment: It is showing an error brother as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when running with other HTML content